# Redirect raw .gif files to handler page via .htacces

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect, web

I have a viral image site where people can view funny gifs. A lot of people on reddit are sharing the raw .gif files however, rather than the page with .gif embedded. This is fine - but I'd like to redirect all people viewing raw image .gifs to a handler page called shareraw.php (located in root directory). This handler page will look exactly the same - just with a share link and button to check out the rest of the site.

I've created the page. All I need now is the correct .htaccess commands to do what I've described. Please help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking the *HTTP_REFERER* for *.gif* requests. If the request isn't coming from your site, you redirect the user to your *shareraw.php* file.

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /uploads/.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shareraw.php?img=$1 [R,L]
```

You'll just need to tweak the rules to accomodate where your viral gifs are stored and how the gif name or path is passed to your *shareraw.php*.

Comment: I shouldn't need to get the exact directory of the gif images, there must be a way to just check if the url ends in a .gif .

Comment: Sure you want that? Because it would start redirecting even sundry gifs used to layout your website (borders, backgrounds etc.) instead of just redirecting the actual viral content.

Comment: Is there a way I can redirect any raw gifs that are directly in the browser? For example a content page on my site might be http://gifsec.com/funny/gif-cat-fight-2/ . I don't want to redirect this content page. The raw image link however is http://gifsec.com/wp-content/uploads/GIF/2014/04/GIF-Cat-fight.gif .  Can't I use HTaccess to just look if the address bar ends in .gif and redirect any users who are just looking at the raw image page? So for example: http://gifsec.com/wp-content/uploads/GIF/2014/04/GIF-Cat-fight.gif  would redirect to whatever.com/shareraw. However not the content page

Comment: Use `%{REQUEST_URI} /uploads/.*\.gif$` as shown in my update. It will redirect all direct browser requests for any .gif uploads to your share page.

Comment: Tried doing that, doesn't seem to be working. This is by htacess file code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382639/redirect-raw-gif-files-to-handler-page-via-htacces-my-code-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment46944481_29382639